# How to set colourbar for scale_fill_distiller

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting a "circle packing chart" with the color of the circles mapped to a value:

```
    # libraries
library(packcircles)
library(ggplot2)

# Create data
data=data.frame(group=paste("Group", letters[1:20]), value=sample(seq(1,100),20)) 

# Generate the layout. This function return a dataframe with one line per bubble. 
# It gives its center (x and y) and its radius, proportional of the value
packing <- circleProgressiveLayout(data$value, sizetype='area')

# We can add these packing information to the initial data frame
data = cbind(data, packing)

# Check that radius is proportional to value. We don't want a linear relationship, since it is the AREA that must be proportionnal to the value
plot(data$radius, data$value)

# The next step is to go from one center + a radius to the coordinates of a circle that
# is drawn by a multitude of straight lines.
dat.gg <- circleLayoutVertices(packing, npoints=50)
dat.gg$value=rep(data$value, each=51)
# Make the plot
ggplot() + 

 # Make the bubbles
  geom_polygon(data = dat.gg, aes(x, y, group = id, fill=value), colour = "black", alpha = 0.6) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "BuPu", direction = 1 , guide="colourbar") +  

  # Add text in the center of each bubble + control its size
  geom_text(data = data, aes(x, y, size=value, label = group)) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(1,4)) +

  # General theme:
  theme_void() + 
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  coord_equal()
```

I would like to display a colourbar next to the plot, so I tried the line:

```
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "BuPu", direction = 1 , guide="colourbar")
```

but that didn't work (no color bar is displayed). What's the correct syntax?

Comment: can you add example of your data (eg., `dput(dat.gg)`). Also, why it didn't work? What's your expected output?

Comment: @PoGibas it's done